# What is the most appropriate ML technology for classifying/recognizing 2D scatter plot shapes?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, pattern-recognition

I would like to be able to automatically classify an input scatter plot into a limited, predefined set of 2-D scatter plots (see attached image), such as a Circle, a Cross, a Straight Line and a Curvy Line - such that, given any new scatter plot as input, the system can correctly categorize it by finding the closest category match.
Ideally, the classification process should also be scale-, translation- and rotation-invariant.
Can anyone suggest an appropriate technology for the training and classification of such 2-D patterns?

[image]

Comment: May I suggest casting the problem into a digit-recognition-like task?  Something similar to building your own MNIST data set.  For this to work, you could create an image or matrix with 1s at the locations of the dots and zeros everywhere else.  I’m currently working in a similar problem where I need to classify particle clouds into lines, corners, or arcs to enable different numerical solvers.  Friends have recommended me to transform a problem into one where a solution is already available, and this seems to be the case here too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need a supervised classifier. Unsupervised method like spectral clustering is designed for this kind of nonlinear clustering problems. The scattered dots will be assumed on a manifold surface instead of in an Euclidian space. Any curvy line could be taken as a manifold surface. Geodesic distance is used for clustering instead of ball-shaped Euclidian distance with manifold kernel.

Comment: If you have already got the initial clusters, you can use KNN to classify the new points as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how does clustering allow me to do **shape recognition**? Aren't _clustering_ and _shape recognition_ two totally different tasks?

Comment: Clustering can only tell you a subset of points should be clustered together, but it is unable to give each subset a label (e.g. a class name or concept). If you also want a label for each cluster, that is a another task indeed.

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't sound like clustering is a solution for this particular problem. It still needs some sort of shape recognition technology.

Comment: If your task is add a new point to a shaped cluster which exists already, use KNN. If you want generate those cluster, and give each cluster a label, that's not a single task, that's two tasks actually.

Comment: No, the task is to **classify** a new scatter plot into one of the 4 predefined scatter plot shapes (see above).

Comment: I guess what is needed for the classification is something like a **non-linear scatter plot correlation coefficient generator**. I'm not sure if neural nets can even be used for this task .